# Why do I get "0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000"

Tags: c++

So in one getter method I'm simply trying to get the length of a c-style string (c-style strings give me headaches) and it works everywhere else in the code except on 1 line stated below the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)

using namespace std;

class MyString
{
private:
    char *str;
public:
    int get_length() const { return strlen(str); }
    char get_string() const { return *str; }
    void display_obj() const
    {
        cout << str << " : " << get_length() << endl;
    }
    MyString()
        :str{nullptr}
    {
        str = new char[1];
        str = '\0';
    }
    MyString(const char *s)
        :str{nullptr}
    {
        str = new char[strlen(s) + 1];
        strcpy(str, s);
    }
    MyString(const MyString &source)
        :str{ nullptr }
    {
        str = new char[strlen(source.str) + 1];
        strcpy(str, source.str);
    }
    MyString(MyString &&source)
        :str{ source.str }
    {
        source.str = nullptr;
    }
    MyString &MyString::operator=(const MyString &source)
    {
        if (this == &source)
            return *this;
        delete[] str;
        str = new char[strlen(source.str) + 1];
        strcpy(str, source.str);
        return *this;
    }
    MyString &MyString::operator=(MyString &&source)
    {
        if (this == &source)
            return *this;
        delete[] str;
        str = source.str;
        source.str = nullptr;
        return *this;
    }
    ~MyString() { delete str; }
};

int main()
{
    MyString a{ "hello" };
    MyString b;
    b.display_obj();
    b = a;
    b.display_obj();
    b = "Tatarusanu";
    b.display_obj();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

and here

```
int get_length() const { return strlen(str); }
```

I get thrown the exception **"Exception thrown at 0x00007FF98602F621 (ucrtbased.dll) in Project1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000"** and I have no idea why. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have a stack trace that says what is calling that `get_length()` method? `0x0000000000000000` is "NULL" basically, so it looks like you're trying to get the length of a string that isn't initialised

Comment: well yeah but whenever i call the method the argument will not be NULL

Comment: I'm practicing overloading operators

Comment: How did this even compile?  The erroneous line `str = '\0';` ought to be a compilation error, or at the very least, a huge warning.

Comment: I'm using the latest verion of Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Professional, I have no clue. I was stupid with that line

Comment: @YakovGalka: Hmm, gcc and clang both reject it as an error.

Comment: @NateEldredge: you seem to be right. Must be MSVC 'extension'?

Comment: `~MyString() { delete str; }` crashes on my machine.  You probably want `~MyString() { delete[] str; }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
MyString()
    :str{nullptr}
{
    str = new char[1];
    //str = '\0'; // <-- here is your mistake
    str[0] = '\0'; // do this instead
}
```

Comment: Or maybe `*str = 0;`

Comment: I replaced "' '" with "" "", thanks!

Comment: @IoanSăsărman If you do, your `delete[]` will fail.

Comment: And an extra brownie point if you fix the undefined behaviour in the destructor.